# bash: How can I detect if the previous command failed, then exit - from inside a function?

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a function in a bash script which accepts a command as an argument, executes the command -- AND -- if the command non-zero exited, abort the script:

file: `command_wrapper.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function exec_cmd() {
    local command=${1}
    $command || exit            # run the command if $? is 1 exit
    if [[ $? -eq 1 ]]           # AGAIN if $? is 1 exit
    then
        echo "command failed"
        exit
    fi

    return 0
}

exec_cmd "grep -R somsomeoemoem ."      # call the function, passing a 
                                        # command that will exit with 1

echo "rest of script running"
```

call it:

```
% ./command_wrapper.sh
./command_wrapper.sh:exec_cmd "grep -R somethingyouwillneverfind ."
rest of script running
```

the script carries on after the function is run with a command that non-zero exits - why?
How can I get this command to error exit when `$command` fails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function works as designed but the issue is your assumption is incorrect. `grep -R somsomeoemoem .` doesn't exit in error.

Try with this command to see the function exiting:

```
exec_cmd "false"
```

Comment: I think my `grep` is returning `1`. when I run this on the command line `% grep -R slkdjfsldkjf . ; echo $?` output is: `1` (im using GNU grep)

Comment: What happens in your case with `exec_cmd "false"` ?

Comment: gah, actually, I think `grep` is returning 0, but for an embarrassing reason, it IS finding the text `somethingyouwillneverfind` - its finding it in its own source code file!

Comment: Ah, you are right :-)

Comment: ah yes, when I use `exec_cmd "false"` it behaves as expected. Thanks for pointing out the `false` command, I will use that from now on!